# Правильно ли составлено предложение? (3)

Tags: грамотная-речь, типы-ошибок

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли составлено предложение? Допущена ли какая-нибудь ошибка?
**Все прохожие в страхе трусливо бегут домой, как увидят перед собой этого человека.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Все прохожие"* - такое широкое обобщение выглядит сомнительно, лучше "все" убрать.

*"в страхе трусливо"* - оставьте из этого что-то одно.

*"как увидят"* - напишите лучше *"едва увидев"*. Можно написать *"как только увидят"*, но "едва" звучит получше (по-моему).

Результат:

*"Прохожие в страхе бегут домой, едва увидев перед собой этого человека"* - по крайней мере, это уже не так режет глаз.

Хотя я бы написал еще короче: *"Прохожие в страхе бегут домой, едва завидев этого человека"*. Вот так это уже выглядит написанным носителем языка.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Все прохожие* — "такое широкое обобщение" никак не выглядит сомнительно.
   Сравните: часть прохожих, несколько прохожих, группа прохожих. А у Вас — **все**, то есть все подряд, массово, скопом, все без исключения.

А. Хайт (к мультфильму про кота Леопольда):
***Все прохожие*** подряд,
Улыбаясь, говорят...

Ю. Дружков («Приключения Карандаша и Самоделкина»):
*Но **все прохожие** громко разговаривали, смеялись, и никто не боялся пирата.*

2. *В страхе трусливо* — не обязательно оставлять что-либо одно. Достаточно, думаю, написать *от страха* и переставить в начало предложения. (Почему, отчего люди бегут? От страха. Как они бегут? Трусливо.)
3. *Бегут домой* — я бы написала *бегут по домам* или *разбегаются по домам*.
4. *...как увидят перед собой...* — эту часть можно варьировать, переставлять и даже отделять тире.

Результатов — множество (все зависит от предыдущего контекста).

Все прохожие — как увидят перед собой этого человека — со страхом разбегаются по домам. От страха все прохожие трусливо разбегаются по домам — лишь видят перед собой этого человека. Все прохожие, как только видят перед собой этого человека, трусливо разбегаются по домам.